# Angular 2 Cross Domain Request

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

Once again I have an issue with angular 2 and I need your help or tips.

I'm working on downloading a file from Amazon S3 in an internal application, which means "all" my request must be authenticated, to do so I added this function in my app.component.ts

```
public initInterceptor(): void {
    let _that = this;
    (function (open) {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
            this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    switch (this.status) {

                        case 401:
                            _that.logout();
                            break;

                        case 200:
                            let token = this.getResponseHeader('Auth');
                            if (token && token != _that.user.token) {
                                _that.user.token = token;
                            }

                            break;
                    }
                }
            }, false);
            open.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
}
```

and my app works just fine, until I try to call my amazon url, which of course doesn't have an "Auth" header because it's a direct call to amazon, so my question is... is there a way to call my amazon url without checking the header in the init interceptor function? like abort the XMLHttpRequest for the moment I get the ArrayBuffer o something. I know that it seems weird but it doesn't make sense to add a header I'm not using.

My downloadattachment call

```
downloadAttachment(downloadUrl: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${downloadUrl._body}`,{responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer})
            .map(this.extractFile)
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.status));
    }

private extractFile(res: Response): Blob {
        let type = res.headers.get('content-type');
        return new Blob([res['_body']], {type: type});
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the URL from the response from `this.responseURL`.
Check if it is not a S3 URL, then extract the Auth header

```
case 200:
    // replace the URL regex placeholder below
    if(!this.responseURL.match(**<Your S3 URL regex>**){
       let token = this.getResponseHeader('Auth');
       if (token && token != _that.user.token) {
         _that.user.token = token;
       }
    }
```